# Stacking one jumbotron on top of each other when reducing screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Main screen showing the problem][image: At a certain screen size they just change height and don't stack]I have placed two jumbotrons side-by-side using auto layout columns on Bootstrap 1 of 2, 2 of 2.
When I reduce the size of the page, the two just resize by going thinner and stretching out the content but I want them to stack on top of each other.
How could I do that? I've tried media queries, but maybe I am not selecting the right 'thing' when targeting the jumbotrons to stack. TIA

```html
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="jumbotron1 jumbotron-fluid" id="register">
                <div class="container1">
                  <h1 class="display-4">Register your interest!</h1>
                  <p class="lead">Festival days will be free, but seats will be limited,
                      so register your interest early and don't miss out!</p>
                  <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                            <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" 
                            placeholder="Enter first name">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col">
                            <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"
                            placeholder="Enter last name">
                          </div>
                  
                        </div>
                        <br>
                          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Which days are you interested in?</h4>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">August 5th</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">August 6th</label>
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">August 7th</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3">
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">August 8th</label>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
                     
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="jumbotron2" id="latestNews">
                <h1 class="display-4">Latest News</h1>
                <div class="list-group">
                   </div>
                    <p class="mb-1"><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/brooklynfest?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" data-tweet-limit="2">Tweets by brooklynfest</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></p>
                  </a>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: You should probably use the Bootstrap resposive col classes ([reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal)). So if you want your `.col` to stack at a lower screen size you could add the class  `col-sm-12` to have it go full width (12 columns) on lower screen resolutions (sm).

Comment: Instead of col use .col-md-6 .col-xs-12, that will do two columns for tablets on up and 1 column for phones

Comment: How would I add this code so that it does go full width of the screen when the desktop screen size is lowered and each jumbotron is stacked like it does when screen size goes thinner?

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-md-6` instead of `col`

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="jumbotron1 jumbotron-fluid" id="register">
        <div class="container1">
          <h1 class="display-4">Register your interest!</h1>
          <p class="lead">Festival days will be free, but seats will be limited, so register your interest early and don't miss out!</p>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter first name">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter last name">
                </div>

              </div>
              <br>
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <h4>Which days are you interested in?</h4>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">August 5th</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">August 6th</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">August 7th</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">August 8th</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="jumbotron2" id="latestNews">
        <h1 class="display-4">Latest News</h1>
        <div class="list-group">
        </div>
        <p class="mb-1"><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/brooklynfest?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" data-tweet-limit="2">Tweets by brooklynfest</a>
          <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/yourpalnurav/pen/pGOpQE?editors=1000)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problems;

when you use only , the colums will share the place you give them. You can give them also a weight, in bootstrap4 a full row has 12 colms. When u say one col-4 and the other one col-8 then they share the screen like 1/3 and 2/3.

Now You can also give them a size, when they should stop breaking lines. They define the min width of your colm. Like col-sm/md/lg/xl(-1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9) e.g. col-md-4.

here stay:

- sm for min-width: 576px
- md for min-width: 768px
- lg for min-width: 992px
- xl for min-width: 1200px

I think md should be ok for you. So use col-md to define your colum: div class="col-**md**"